# onChildRemoved Listener for a nested node in Firebase does not work

Tags: java, firebase

[image]

I have a ChildEventListener on the "subjects" node like this:

```
    mSubjectsFirebase.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          // This does not get called when I delete the blue circled item.
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

onChildRemoved does not get called when I delete the item circled blue.
So how do know if the blue item has been deleted?

I don't want to put the ChildEventListener onto the node under it because it is a push() node and there will be hundreds of them..

Answer (score 1):

The [Firebase API documentation for Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ChildEventListener) doesn't say much about the child events. (The [JavaScript documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#on) is a little more comprehensive.)

However, there is more detail in one of the [Android guides](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data#child-events):

> The **onChildChanged()** callback is triggered any time a child node is modified. *This includes any modifications to descendants of the child node.*

The documentation does not explicitly state that the others do not include descendants of the child node, but my experience - and yours - suggests that the `onChildChanged()` callback is the only one that is triggered for descendants of the child node.

Unfortunately, the Android API differs from the JavaScript and iOS APIs in a way that is going to make it difficult to solve your problem.

With the JavaScript and iOS APIs it's possible to listen to a specific event. For example, using JavaScript, I'd call `on("child_removed", (snapshot) => { ... })`. With the Android API, all of the child events have been incorporated into a single listener and - as far as I can see - there is no way you can add a [`ChildEventListener`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ChildEventListener) that listens only to the event that corresponds to the `onChildRemoved` function.